# Can i send json data by corebluetooth frame work?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am creating a application to send JSON data using CoreBluetooth.framework. As offline data passing to particular device in a region.

Comment: Where do you want to pass that data to??

Comment: to another ios device with the same app.

Comment: yes you can see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you could send any kind of data as NSData objects to all your bluetooth peripheral devices.

The implementation has been done in the [sample app](https://github.com/0x7fffffff/Core-Bluetooth-Transfer-Demo), they pass a **NSData value** of a **NSString**, you could possibly do the same - convert your **JSON dict** to **NSString** and using **dataUsingEncoding:** method of **NSString** and send the **NSData** object to your peripheral device.

**Note:** See the Peripheral tab which sends the text in the UITextView to another BLE device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i use the above sample app but the problem is that that cbcharacteristic.value read full data on buffer not one by one like socket